# Change element's visibility when javascript calls a function in a WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm building a simple android app based on a WebView of a website that I personally built, so I'm just making the mobile app for it that shows the mobile version of the website. The app has an adMob Ad at the top of the page that I want to hide in certain cases after the user logs in(for example because he has a different account type and ads can't be shown when he logs in). So I tried using addJavascriptInterface to my WebView and calling a function from javascript when the Ad needs to be hidden but I can't make it work. I'm new to android programming so it may be I'm just missing something fundamental but I couldn't find an answer anywhere on internet. Here's my code:
MainActivity:

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
     mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

     mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, mAdView), "Android");

     // Enable Javascript
     WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
     webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

     absoluteUrl = "myWebSiteUrl";
     mWebView.loadUrl(absoluteUrl);
     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(this, mAdView));
    }
}
```

WebAppInterface:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
Context mContext;
AdView mAdView;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c, AdView mAdView) {
    this.mContext = c;
    this.mAdView = mAdView;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page and hide the Ad */
@JavascriptInterface
public void hideAd(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
}
```

Javascript code in my page

```
  //..Some variables here
  var accountType = 1;

  $(document).ready(function() {
     if (accountType == 1) {
          Android.hideAd('The Ad is now hidden');                   
     }
  //Other js functions
```

It works when in hideAd() I only show the toast, but when I add

```
mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The Ad at the top doesn't hide and all the javascript code in the page no longer works, please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.